# Python equivalent to Ruby Array.each method

Tags: python, ruby

In Python what is equivalent to Ruby's Array.each method? Does Python have a nice and short closure/lambda syntax for it?

```
[1,2,3].each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> Does Python have a nice and short closure/lambda syntax for it?

Yes, but you don't want it in this case.

The closest equivalent to that Ruby code is:

```
new_values = map(print, [1, 2, 3])
```

That looks pretty nice when you already have a function lying around, like `print`. When you just have some arbitrary expression and you want to use it in `map`, you need to create a function out of it with a `def` or a `lambda`, like this:

```
new_values = map(lambda x: print(x), [1, 2, 3])
```

That's the ugliness you apparently want to avoid. And Python has a nice way to avoid it: comprehensions:

```
new_values = [print(x) for x in values]
```

However, in this case, you're just trying to execute some statement for each value, not accumulate the new values for each value. So, while this will work (you'll get back a list of `None` values), it's definitely not idiomatic.

In this case, the right thing to do is to write it explicitly—no closures, no functions, no comprehensions, just a loop:

```
for x in values:
    print x
```

Comment: This is probably the best and most complete answer since it actually addressed the issues of lambdas stated in the question which my answer did not. +1

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that my specific examples only work in Python 3.x (or, in 2.6-2.7, if you do a `from __future__ import print_function`); maybe I should have used `sys.stdout.write` or something as a rough equivalent of `puts` instead of `print` to avoid this… But if you understood everything, I guess it's good enough.

Comment: each doesn't return any value, unlike map.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Right, but Python doesn't have an "each". And, more importantly, it doesn't have _any_ expression syntax for mutating things when you don't care about the return value. And that's intentional. If you want a value, you can do it in an expression; if you don't, there's no reason not to just use a statement, as my answer says.

Answer (score 12):

The most idiomatic:

```
for x in [1,2,3]:
    print x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy for vectorized arithmetic over an array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a * 3
array([3, 6, 9])
```

You can easily define a lambda that can be used over each element of an array:

```
>>> array_lambda=np.vectorize(lambda x: x * x)
>>> array_lambda([1, 2, 3])
array([1, 4, 9])
```

But as others have said, if you want to just print each, use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are also libraries that wrap objects to expose all the usual functional programming stuff.

- PyDash http://pydash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- underscorepy (Google `github underscore.py`)

E.g. pydash allows you to do things like this:

```
>>> from pydash import py_
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> x = py_([1,2,3,4]).map(lambda x: x*2).each(print).value()
2
4
6
8
>>> x
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

(Just always remember to "trigger" execution and/or to un-wrap the wrapped values with `.value()` at the end!)

Comment: What I personally like about writing code like this is that it reads left-to-right. It's easier to follow the data/value flows.

Answer (score 1):

without need of an assignment:

```
list(print(_) for _ in [1, 2, 3])
```

or just

```
[print(_) for _ in [1, 2, 3]]
```